# dbus-daemon can not started

Tags: homebrew, launchd

I have MBP M1, and install dbus with homebrew, but it sounds that dbus was not started. How can I start dbus?

dbus version: 1.12.20

Thanks

```
$ brew services
Name    Status  User      Plist
dbus    started lidaobing /Users/lidaobing/Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist
emacs   started lidaobing /Users/lidaobing/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.emacs.plist
unbound stopped
$ ps aux | grep dbus
lidaobing         7767   0.0  0.0 408114560   1392 s001  S+   11:32AM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto dbus
$ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dbus/1.12.20/bin/dbus-daemon --nofork --session
dbus-daemon[7816]: Failed to start message bus: Check-in failed: No such process
```

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution at the end? I am getting crazy for the same reason...

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 still no answer for this, I want to use this for `GNotification`, at last, I write a mac notifier with `terminal-notifier`: https://github.com/iptux-src/iptux/blob/master/src/iptux/TerminalNotifierNotificationService.cpp